# handlebar file manager img tag replacement

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I am working on a project with a file manager(dropbox like), and i am using handlebars template to show each file that i am uploading into a div.
the problem is that i want to show a preview of the file in the web page but at this moment only images are showing. is there any other tags i could replace img with?

```
<div class="file">
<a href="{{upload.url}}" target="_blank">
  <span class="corner"></span>
  <div class="image">
    <img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="{{upload.url}}">
  </div>
```

i am trying to replace the img alt to show a preview of a file (pdf, text, ect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use an iframe like this.

```
 <iframe src="{{upload.url}}"></iframe>
```